# Chromatic polynomial of this graph

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, coloring

Here's the graph I'm working on, I want to find its chromatic polynomial, as well as how many proper colorings are possible using $4$ colors.

[image]

For the first question, the polynomial I came up with is $x(x-1)^4(x-2)^2$ (because $e,f,b,c$ have similar properties, so do $a$ and $d$) does that look correct? I've heard about Birkhoff’s theorem but I'm not sure when can I apply that.

Apart from the chromatic polynomial approach, can I proceed with the second part from combinatorics? There're $7$ vertices and $4$ colors, to find proper colorings, should that be $\binom{7}4-9$ (as there're $9$ edges in total)? Thanks!

Comment: Why would yo need combinatorics if the chromatic polynomial tells you how many proper colorings are there. Can you describe how did you get the polynomial? Also do you know the contraction deletion algorithm?

Comment: @Phicar Thanks, I just updated the question:)

Comment: $(x-1) x (5 - 4 x + x^2) (-5 + 7 x - 4 x^2 + x^3)$ gives 1380 4-colourings

Comment: @flinty Thanks! Could you give some hints about how to obtain the polynomial?

Comment: Use a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deletion%E2%80%93contraction_formula .

Comment: As a hint (or rather to avoid doing the work myself), you could use an extension of the reasoning for [determining the chromatic polynomial of a ladder graph](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/602109/chromatic-polynomial-of-ladder-graph) which is very close to your graph. Or you can use the deletion contraction formula and write out a binary tree of graphs to help with the calculation.

Answer (score 1):

I just figured out this question by using Birkloff's theorem twice. First we can remove the edge $ad$ and obtain $H = G-ad$ and $G/ad$. For graph $H$, we can apply the theorem one more time for edge $dc$. We will finally obtain the polynomial and figure out there're $1380$ 4-colorings. Thanks all for the help!